how cpp-ZXing generate QR Code with Wide Characters?
#include "ReadBarcode.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

#include "BitMatrix.h"
#include "BitMatrixIO.h"
#include "CharacterSet.h"
#include "MultiFormatWriter.h"


#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image_write.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>

using namespace ZXing;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    int sizeHint = 100;
    auto format = BarcodeFormatFromString("QRCode");
    auto writer = MultiFormatWriter(format).setMargin(10);

    //writer.setEncoding(CharacterSet::UTF8);
    
    // this will work with char*
    BitMatrix matrix = writer.encode("ddd", sizeHint, sizeHint);
    
     /* with Chinese charaters, the QR Code will be generated, but it 
     cannot be recognized by online public QR scanner.
     I've tried serveral ways. */

     // attempt 1. directly replace the paramter with `const w_char*`
     // BitMatrix matrix = writer.encode(L"你好", sizeHint, sizeHint);

    // attempt 2. build a std::wstring
    // std::wtring word = L"你好";
   // BitMatrix matrix = writer.encode(word, sizeHint, sizeHint);
   
    auto bitmap = ToMatrix<uint8_t>(matrix);
    int success = stbi_write_png("C:\\Users\\chenz\\Desktop\\2.png", bitmap.width(), bitmap.height(), 1, bitmap.data(), 0);

    if (!success) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to write image: " << std::endl;
            return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "qrcode done " << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


here is the my code for generate a QR Code Image to the Desktop.
It works fine. But if I change the encode content to something containing wide characters, it corrupts. I notice that the encode methods receive both std::string and std::wstring, I pass in the wide charaters with L as heading, but in vain.
this QR Code image below is the second attempt result and enabling utf-8 encoding, not matched with the information I've input


Why did you disable UTF-8 encoding? QR codes need to encode your wide characters to some byte string.

@Botje it seems this line do no impact for the result

Then please edit your question with an example text that fails to render properly.

I built and ran your example on my Mac and it works fine with UTF-8 encoding. Are you certain that your compiler is configured to match the encoding of the wide string in your source file?

@Botje I've got it, by setting the encoding, and passing in char* rather than w_char* will work

I think that means your compiler's charset setting does not match what bytes are in your file. Since a char* is treated as Utf8.

If you do not set a character set, you run into this bit of code inside QREncoder.cpp:
    bool charsetWasUnknown = charset == CharacterSet::Unknown;
    if (charsetWasUnknown) {
        charset = DEFAULT_BYTE_MODE_ENCODING;
    }

where
static const CharacterSet DEFAULT_BYTE_MODE_ENCODING = CharacterSet::ISO8859_1;

This can only represent a tiny fraction of the full Unicode codepoints set, so you should specify UTF-8 encoding instead.
